# short variable dump is not proper inside structure

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Below is the code snippet,

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct container {
    int myint;
    long mylong;
    short myshort;
}__attribute__((packed));

int main()
{
    struct container con = {.myint = 0x12345678,
        .mylong = 0x12345678,
        .myshort = 0xABCD};
    int i;
    char *ptr = (char *)&con;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%x ", *ptr);
        ++ptr;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
78 56 34 12 78 56 34 12 ffffffcd ffffffab
```

Why short variable values are `ffffffcd` and `ffffffab` instead of `cd` and `ab`?
Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: The `char` values passed to `printf()` are converted to `int`, and on your machine/compiler, `char` is a signed type, so the values like 0xCD and 0xAB become negative 4-byte integers, and they're printed with the leading `0xFFFFFF` because that's how negative integers are stored/represented.

Answer (score 3):

Make ptr `unsigned char *` instead of `char *`. Also your loop limit should be `sizeof(con)`, not 10.

Comment: You have given solution but what is the reason of the behaviour?

Comment: The short answer: a bare `char` can be either signed or unsigned (depending on compiler & compile options). In your case they're signed. When the char argument is passed to printf, signed chars are sign extended -- 0x80 becomes 0xffffff80 -- while unsigned chars are zero-extended -- 0x80 becomes 0x00000080 (both assuming 32-bit integers).

Comment: What is "sign extended"? It gets promoted to `int` and since the `char` is a signed type, the sign is preserved, simple as that.

Comment: @Lundin -- What you describe below as "sign preservation" is actually called sign extension. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension for details. The x86 architecture has specific instructions for sign-extending (MOVSX) and zero-extending (MOVZX) values. I assume other architectures have similar instructions.

Comment: @keithmo That may be so, but what you describe is the consequence, not the cause.

Comment: @Lundin The cause of the OP's problem is that signed chars are sign-extended when promoted to ints when passed to printf(). We're saying the same thing, you're just using nonstandard terminology.

Comment: @keithmo No, you are. The integer promotions (ISO 9899:2011 6.3.1.1) state "If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. **The integer promotions preserve value including sign.** As discussed earlier, whether a ‘‘plain’’ char is treated as signed is implementation-defined."

Comment: @Lundin Fair point -- I had not checked the exact verbage in the spec. That said, I still maintain that we're both describing the same thing -- you're describing what the compiler does ("preserve the sign"), and I'm describing how it does it (or at least how it does it on a two's complement machine).

Answer (score 0):

The `char` type is unsuitable for storing integer values as it has implementation-defined signedness. Meaning that it, unlike any other integer type, may be either signed or unsigned depending on compiler. In your case it is signed, so any raw byte value larger than `0x7F` will get treated as negative.

If such a `char` variable would at some point get promoted to `int`, it would have the negative value preserved, 0xCD turns into 0xFFFFFFCD etc.

`printf`, and all other variable argument list functions, always promote the parameters passed to it according to a weird rule called "the default argument promotions". All small integer types such as `char` or `short` etc get promoted to `int` and all `float` get promoted to `double`.

In your case, the `char` got promoted to `int` and the sign was preserved. To avoid problems like this, never use `char` for anything except storing characters. Instead, do like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)&con;
```